# Multiple Content slider on mobile webpage

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, html

My site is divided into number of categories like travel, lifestyle etc.

I want to create a mobile webpage for the site where all categories are listed vertically. Under each category, a content slider is there to show latest posts and these are clickable.

Site will be for only android and iPhone devices.

You can have a look at basic UI here :

http://floost.com/mob/mob1/explore.html

Any ideas on how to achieve this? or examples to see whether they have already been achieved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Akshat Goel dont what exactly you are lookin for but if you want a div with slide animation i.e on a button click it will come and go wiht slide animation

then you can use the following wiht it

```
$('#YOUR_DIV').show("slow")

$('#YOUR_DIV').hide("slow")
```

Comment: Thanks for the try but this is not the thing I am looking for.